# Can I deduct driving expenses when I am driving for Uber?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, small-business

A person is driving for Uber. He gets in his car and turns on the Uber app.  After some time, he gets a rider. He then drives to pick up the rider. After that, he gets another rider. He repeats this for 8 hours. At the end of the 8 hours he drives home.

It is my belief that all the driving he did is deductible as a business expense. Am I right about that?

I am in the United States.

Comment: "Driving" is not an expense. What expenses are you asking about? Wear and tear? Fuel?

Comment: @Acccumulation I was thinking of the $0.53 per mile you can deduct.

Comment: @Acccumulation Because of the mileage deduction, “driving” really is an expense, and it doesn’t need to be broken out any more than that, if you choose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the United States a ride share driver is a part of the Gig economy. The IRS even has a [Gig Economy Tax Center](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/gig-economy-tax-center).

You will eventually find [Pub 463. Travel, Gift, and Car Expenses.](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p463#en_US_2020_publink100033930)

It boils down to to options. a standard rate for every mile you drive for business, or calculating the actual expenses:

> Actual car expenses include:
>
> - Depreciation
> - Licenses
> - Lease payments
> - Registration fees
> - Gas
> - Insurance
> - Repairs
> - Oil
> - Garage rent
> - Tires
> - Tolls
> - Parking fees

Regarding  parking and tolls

Parking fees and tolls.

> In addition to using the standard mileage rate, you can deduct any
> business-related parking fees and tolls. (Parking fees you pay to park
> your car at your place of work are nondeductible commuting expenses.)

You have to take careful records of the miles. I know that first miles, and last miles each day have to be addressed. I know that miles while waiting for the next customer have to be addressed also. I would review all the IRS items in the Gig economy tax center for more details.

Comment: Just one thing which would be worth clarifying in your answer. The OP also stated: "at the end of the 8 hours he drives home". In my jurisdiction that would be non-deductible as it part of getting to/from work rather than being part of the work itself. Would that be the case in the US too?

Comment: @JBentley I think they would need to contrive some reasonable "depot" to call their place of business, from which reasonable Uber business could be had.  For instance if they live out a country road and must drive 10 miles to get to an area where you have a good likelihood of picking up a ride rapidly, then that.  If you are at such a customer area and repositioning *for a better customer area*, that should be deductible. A real judgment call there, but "Uber advising you to do that" would be very favorable.